# Add/Remove form validations with data attributes on the fly using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation Plugin to work with form validation that too using data attributes like

```
<input type="text" class="firstName" name="firstName" data-rule-required="true" />
```

**JSFiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/SLXhR/135/

**Normal Scenario:**
It works well if i didn't click on submit button and change the dropdown values and click the submit button.

**Problematic Scenario:**
As soon as i click on submit button then try to change the dropdown value. It  won't disable/enable required validation.

**Steps to reproduce the actual issue**

- Hit form submit button to fire the required field validation
- Input field will show up the error message
- Now change the country dropdown value to make input field non required
- Error message should disappear this time but it is not the case

**JavaScript**

```
$('#validate-me-plz').validate();

$("#country").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === "country1") {
        if($('.firstName').attr('data-rule-required') !== 'true') {
            $('.firstName').attr('data-rule-required','true');    
        }
    } else if($(this).val() === "country2") {
        if($('.firstName').attr('data-rule-required') !== 'false') {
            $('.firstName').attr('data-rule-required','false');    
        }
    }
});
```

Please guide me to get the resolution for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data` instead of `attr` and instead of setting string `true` or `false` set a `bool` value

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/SLXhR/136/)**

```
$("#country").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() === "country1") {
        if(!$('.firstName').data('rule-required')) { //check bool value
            $('.firstName').data('rule-required',true);    //set bool value
        }
    } else if($(this).val() === "country2") {
        if($('.firstName').data('rule-required')) {
            $('.firstName').data('rule-required',false);    
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is working as expected. Let me incorporate this code is actual application. Thanks a lot Guru for your prompt response.

Comment: Anytime.. Do not forget to mark as answer if this solved your problem @Lokesh.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Will surely do that Guru.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the .rules('remove') method only works on rules added via the rules-option or via the .rules('add') method (per the docs), so that won't work for data attribute rules.  That might help someone avoid consternation if they were looking for another way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @jinglesthula I never knew that part in form validation and if that is true instead of the above method OP can `add` or `remove` rules based on condition and yea the above answer may be the work around..